# How to get the seperate column of the comma seperated following data with the column names like ID, Address, Locality, City, State

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test_addresses.csv',sep=',')
df.head(10)

ID  Address
0   1   Near Wagheshwar Temple, Wagholi, Pune, Maharas...
1   2   Magarpatta, Pune, Magarpatta, Pune, Maharashtra
2   3   Manikbaug Sinhgad Road Pune, Sinhgad Road, Pun...
3   4   Kothrud, Pune, Maharashtra
4   5   Pimple Nilakh, Pune, Maharashtra
5   6   Opposite To D Mart And Next To Cybage It, Kalyan
6   7   Pune, Pimple Nilakh, Pune, Maharashtra
7   8   Flat No15 , 2nd Floor, Near Jakat Naka,Pune, B
8   9   Wagholi, Pune, Maharashtra
9   10  Wakad Near Euro School, Shankar Kalat Nagar, B
```

By using the Address column comma seperated data we want to split them

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
cols = ['Address','Locality', 'City', 'State']
df = pd.DataFrame({"Address":["Near Wagheshwar Temple, Wagholi, Pune, Maharastra",
"Manikbaug Sinhgad Road Pune, Sinhgad Road, Pune, Maharastra","Wagholi, Pune, Maharashtra"]})

def create_col(x):
    split = x['Address'].split(",")
    for i in range(len(cols)-len(split)):
        split.insert(i,'')
    return split
        
df[cols] =  df.apply(create_col,axis = 1, result_type ='expand')
df
```

Result

[image]

Comment: getting an error as 
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain your expected output very easily using `series.str.split()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[0,1],"Address":["Near Wagheshwar Temple, Wagholi, Pune, Maharastra",
"Manikbaug Sinhgad Road Pune, Sinhgad Road, Pune, Maharastra"]})

cols = ['Address','Locality', 'City', 'State']
df[cols] = pd.DataFrame(df.Address.str.split(",").to_list(), columns = cols)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Getting an error TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: If you try my complete code then it should work. If you try it with your data then the error maybe because of nan values..

Comment: No this is not working on my actual dataframe

Comment: Solution is proper thats why its workingv on my data.. Can you share your dataset?

Comment: Adresses are incomplete. Share the dictionary of the dataset instead.

Comment: Length of data is in variable-length form so it is difficult to get data in each column